# Problema al renombrar strings dentro de un archivo

Tags: c#, str-replace

estoy intentando renombrar partes de codigo dentro de un archivo pero no consigo que me funcione.
Supongo que sera un problema de novato pero no logro saber el porque...
El código es el siguiente;

```
        string[] lineas = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Jose\Desktop\ar1.txt");

        foreach (var linea in lineas)
        {

            linea.Replace("JPm123", "JPm98");
        }

        File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Jose\Desktop\ar1.txt", lineas);
```

¿Poque al ejecutar el codigo el codigo sigue siendo el mismo? Sin embargo, en tiempo de ejecucion si que veo que el metodo `Replace()` sustituye correctamente el valor en cada linea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vayamos a la documentación de [String.Replace](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_):

> Devuelve una **nueva cadena** en la que todas las apariciones de una
>   cadena especificada en la instancia actual se reemplazan por otra
>   cadena especificada.

Es decir, `Replace` no sustituye en la cadena fuente, sino que devuelve una nueva cadena con la sustitución hecha.

Dicho esto, lo que debes hacer es igualar la cadena original al resultado de `Replace`:

```
string[] lineas = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Jose\Desktop\ar1.txt");

for (int i=0; i<lineas.Length-1; i++)
{
    lineas[i] = lineas[i].Replace("JPm123", "JPm98");
}

File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Jose\Desktop\ar1.txt", lineas);
```

Si te fijas, he sustituido el bucle `foreach` por `for`, dado que en un bucle `foreach` no se pueden modificar los elementos que se recorren.

Answer (score 2):

Replace no muta la cadena original, devuelve una nueva mutada. Tendrías que asignarla a una nueva variable, algo como esto:

```
    List<string> lineasNuevas = new List<string>();
    foreach (var linea in lineas)
    {

        lineasNuevas.Add(linea.Replace("JPm123", "JPm98"));
    }

    File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Jose\Desktop\ar1.txt", lineasNuevas);
```